How to redefine chapter*
I would like to save the name of the chapter* sections to a variable and to achieve this I am trying to redefine the chapter* command, how could I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
\renewcommand{\chapter*}[1]{\chapter*{#1} \def\lname{#1}}


You can't. You would have to redefine the internal command which LaTeX uses when it finds a star immediately following \chapter. The star isn't actually part of the command name as far as TeX is concerned. Instead, \chapter is defined in such a way that one internal command gets chosen if it is followed by a star and another if it is not. (This is over-simplified, but that's the overall effect of what's done.)

got it thank you very much

You already asked this a couple of days ago: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719251/redefine-chapter-format.

To be fair, a couple days ago was a different aspect of \chapter*.  I think there are ways to accomplish this, but it probably depends on what you're wanting to do with the saved name.

@Teepeemm That's why I didn't vote to close, but it is basically the same issue and if the OP is using egreg's answer to the earlier question, asking this one without providing that information is just likely result in incompatible code. E.g. if I answered this question, I wouldn't use titlesec which would make my answer incompatible with egreg's. (I realise you know all this.)

You've already been told in comments to previous question that you should show not only a code snippet, but a minimal working example. You should try doing this always. As cfr explained above using package like titlesec and how using it is relevant for an answer. And (at least if not using titlesec) the used class would also be relevant.

A minimal working example here is almost infeasible to post since it would be far too long since I'm writing my own package right now, so I apologize for that.

You should not show your whole own package, but a minimal working example as explained in the link I've posted in my comment and as shown, e.g., by egreg in the answer to your previous question.

Assuming you are using egreg's answer to your earlier question you could pick up the name in \managechapter. For example,
\makeatletter
\newcommand\lname{}
\newcommand{\managechapter}[1]{%
  #1% print the title
  \if@mainmatter
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}% send to the toc
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}% like book does usually
  \fi
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\lname{#1}% 
}
\makeatother

This assumes you only want to pick the name up in unnumbered chapters. So \lname will still expand to Introduction in chapter 1.
I'm not going to post complete code because I'm not comfortable posting code which uses titlesec. There's nothing wrong with it. I just don't get along with it, which means I can't answer any queries about code which uses it. However, I did test the complete code ;).
